# Unknown tree in my back yard

Tags: identification

This thing is growing at the edge of my back yard. What is it? (It has a sort of leathery looking bark, if it matters.)

[image]

Comment: For identification, it would be nice if you add some information about location (continent/region, climate, mountains). Is bark "reddish"? Horizontal lines?

Comment: Region is northeastern US, on the coast. I'll post more photos ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

Where is the tree ? Black cherry would be one possibility. A photo of a larger area would help.